# How to view the waveform of a music sample?

Tags: audio

Does anyone know how to view the waveform of music sample ? More specifically is there any free software which will graph out the wave which is produced by that sound so I can record it and try to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is a open source software for recording and editing sounds, which will show the sound file as wave form. I hope this helps.

[image]